# gnome-tweaks not Running in Ubuntu

Tags: gnome-tweaks

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

So, I try to Change my ubuntu Desktop using gnome-tweaks
So I ran the Command

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

After that i try to launch it it shows me an error

```
GLib-GIO-ERROR **: 23:30:51.451: Settings schema 'org.gnome.tweaks' is not installed
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

Im stuck here

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Comment: Please add the this information in your question.

Comment: Try `sudo add-apt-repository universe` followed by `sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool` . if they succeed search for tweaks or open using Terminal with `gnome-tweaks`

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 basic steps to install GNOME Tweaks Tool in 22.04 LTS

1. Check if the tool is already installed: In terminal run `gnome-tweaks`. If its not installed, do so with `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`
2. Update and upgrade the system. `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt upgrade`
3. Enable the Universe Repository `sudo apt-add-repository universe` The system then asks you to press the enter key and proceeds to install and enable the Universal repository on your system.
4. Install the GNOME Tweaks Tool `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`

Finally, launch the GNOME Tweaks Tool by either searching for `tweaks` or launch from terminal after its installed `gnome-tweaks`

[image]

[reference](https://bytexd.com/how-to-install-and-use-gnome-tweaks-tool-in-ubuntu/)

Comment: I tried it didn;t work

Comment: I just ran these commands in 22.04.1 and they worked perfectly. Just saying "it didn't work" is insufficient. Please explain more about what you did and any error messages displayed. Best to [edit] your question with those reasons so that you can be helped.

Comment: I already said it every time i run it. it shows me

```
GLib-GIO-ERROR **: 23:30:51.451: Settings schema 'org.gnome.tweaks' is not installed
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)

Comment: very time you run what? There are 4 commands to run if the tool is not installed. Please edit your original question with the information rather than just add to the comment trail on the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, try the below command in your terminal it worked for me.

`sudo /usr/bin/glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/`

The problem is with the Glib schemas which are not compiled on your system.

References:-

- [glassfish no start GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'org.gnome.system.proxy' is not installed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61007724/6194097)
- [Error: GLib-GIO-ERROR: Settings schema 'org.blueman.general' is not installed #274](https://github.com/blueman-project/blueman/issues/274)
- [GLib-GIO-ERROR**: No GSettings schemas are installed on the system](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28953973/6194097)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).